# Converting String to Character in PHP

Tags: php, xml, string, wsdl, character

I'm developing an application where it uses SOAP calls to another server. SOAP uses an WSDL(XML) which defines all properties and types of every object. All of the logic is being developed in PHP.

The problem is that the WSDL is expecting a character object. Is there any way with PHP how I can convert an obejct from a String into a Char? The WSDL file cannot be altered from the provider since there are many other clients which makes use of this WSDL.

I have tried the following with no success.

```
$year = $_POST['birthdayYear'];
$property['birthdayYear'] = chr($year);
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You need to supply the relevant part of the WSDL, otherwise it will all be guessing.

Comment: What's a "character object"? There ain't objects in XML :-?

Answer (score 0):

[`chr()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.chr.php) gets the ascii value passed by parameter and converts it into a character. In fact, a string is a sequence of characters, so I don't see a point on this. If you prefer to have a list of characters, use [`str_split()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php) (again, I'm not sure that you really want that)